# JPA Repository Max & Min values

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-jpa

Есть репозиторий:

```
 public interface DetailRepository extends JpaRepository<Detail, Integer>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вытащить из него посредством существующих методов минимальное и максимальное значение по какому-либо полю. Наверно вообще как-то элементарно, но я не нашел ни Max, Min, Value Top, Bottom, может как-то по-особенному называются? )

Comment: JpaRepository это что? Точнее из какого фреймворка?

Comment: org.springframework.data    
spring-data-jpa

Comment: Вы можете сделать Query и в нем использовать max/min/top/bot.

Comment: Это понятно, но неужели нет существующих методов? Или min/max настолько редко используют? Может как-то через сортировку с выборкой по первому?

Comment: @vinsler https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords Как видите, 'min' и 'max' нет.

Comment: Но их можно получить через JPQL , что-то вроде Query(select min(d.id) from detail d)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, если есть возможность пару простых примеров в коде методов или ссылок? Если найду раньше, добавлю сам.

Comment: Пишу так не работает, ссылок не нашел:
    @Query (value = "Select min(d.count) from detail d", nativeQuery = true)
    Detail findMinimum();

Comment: @vinsler Правильно, потому что вы выбираете одно значение (инт) , а хотите, чтобы метод вернул Detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выбрать первый элемент из отсортированного списка:

```
Detail findFirstByRequiredOrderByCountAsc(Boolean required);
```

И у детали уже взять count, это и будет минимальным значением.

Comment: Да так и сделал, вместо @Query с нативным запросом, можно проще написать так и в контроллере или сервисе уже вытащить число, например:
Integer detailMinCount = serviceClassDetail.findFirstByRequiredOrderByCountAsc().getCount();

Answer (score 0):

1) Нет существующих методов для обработки данного запроса в репозитории JPARepository. Поэтому это можно сделать только через Query.

2) Примерный запрос выглядит так:

```
@Query (value = "Select min(d.count) from detail d", nativeQuery = true)
Integer findMinimum();
```

Comment: В итоге запрос получился следующим:
    @Query (value = "Select min(d.count) from (SELECT*From detail where required = true) d", nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий метод:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT max(w.id) from Word w")
Integer findMaximum();
```